# RegExp duplicated elements

Tags: javascript, regex

I have such a string

`www -aaa - ddd - xxx`

and want to remove everything after the **SECOND** `-`. For this example the result needs to look like this:

`www -aaa`

I've tried this regex:

```
((-|–).*)((-|–).*)
```

but it matches everything starting from the first dash, and I'm not familiar with regex :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use capturing group.

```
> var s = 'www -aaa - ddd - xxx '
undefined
> s.replace(/(-[^-]*).*/, '$1')
'www -aaa '
> s.replace(/(-[^-]*)\b.*/, '$1')
'www -aaa'
```

Comment: And if I want to remove not just after second  `-` but after a group of symbols like `+` `--` etc ?

Comment: `s.replace(/(-.*?)\+.*/, '$1')`

Comment: nono I mean if my srings wiil look like `w - a -d` `w + a +d` `w -- a --d` and I want to remove after second `-` `+` `--` etc

Answer (score 0):

Also can acquired without regexes.

```js
var str="www -aaa - ddd - xxx";
str=str.split("-").slice(0,2).join("-")
alert(str)
```